# Pandas groupby two columns and output values from 3rd column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
colour    num    accepted  returned
grey      1      yes       no
red       2      no        no
grey      4      yes       yes
```

I have the dataframe above and want to output unique combinations of `colour` and `num` columns and also the corresponding value in `returned`, as below

```
colour    num     returned
grey      1       no    
red       2       no      
grey      4       yes
```

Using `df.groupby(['colour', 'num']).size()` gives me unique combinations but not the `returned` column.

Comment: What should `returned` contain, if there is another row `grey-1-yes-yes`?

Comment: are you looking for this one `df['size']=df.groupby(['colour', 'num'])['num'].transform('size')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think you should to group the `returned` column as well.

`df.groupby(['colour','num','returned']).size()`

This will display the number of occurences of each returned status, grouped by `num` and `colour`:

```
colour  num  returned
grey    1    no          1
        4    yes         1
red     2    no          1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the combination of colour and num is unique, you can just do:

```
df.groupby(['colour', 'num'])['returned'].max()
```

Of course, if it's not really unique and there is both a 'yes' and 'no' this will return 'yes' because 'yes' > 'no'...

But actually, this solution doesn't give anything else than `df[['colour','num','returned']].drop_duplicates()`, which is definitely leaner.

If somehow you know that rows can be repeated *but* the returned value is unique and you want at the same time the number of times it appears and the unique value in "returned", you can do it in one go with:

```
df.groupby(['colour','num'])['returned'].agg(['size','max'])
```

Which would return:

```
            size    max
colour  num     
grey    1   1       no
        4   1       yes
red     2   1       no
```